# Can't update my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a profile image upload.
I have cureently made it so you can upload a file to my server and it gets a random name.

The problem i have now is that i cant update my mysql table so it have a profile picture.

This is my code for checking so the file is okay.

```
 <div class="profile">
  <?php

    if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true ) {
        if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
            echo "Please chose a file";
        } else {

                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
                }   else {
                    echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed - ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
        }
    }


    if (empty($user_data['profile']) === false) {
        echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'],'" alt="',$user_data['userName'],'s Profilepicture">';
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="profile"><input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Then my othercode php script wher i give it a random name and want to upload to mysql database.

[THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQnS.png)

[image]
if someone knows what im doing wrong plss help me.

**UPDATE**

So the problem I have is that i can't update my mysql tbale. Everythinbg else works fine. Its just that when I try to change my `['profile']` tab in my mysql table it dosent work. I try to change my  `['profile']` with the `$file_path`.

Comment: It will be great you update your post with little more detail. What error do you get? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I hvae updated it now, read the text at the bottom :D

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: there's no db code here, just an image of it and that image of it, clearly shows that you're mixing MySQL APIs. You're also using a class and functions. This question cannot be solved in its present state.

Answer (score -1):

your action is blank. you might want to fill it first.

Answer (score -1):

If action is blank by default it will send the post request to same page,  so that does not effects database insertion.

Check your database structure the column for taking profiles is varchar or what ?

Comment: @RobinFors: do you mind to update your post with your comment above for all?

Comment: Make sure your $file_path do not increase 50 characters and or increase profile to varchar 255